# Volume icon in the way of GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't seem to get rid of this white volume icon infront of the `GameObject` - which means I can't see the `GameObject`:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Turn off the gizmos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click Gizmos option and you can resize icons
[image]